# Unicorn w/ Sinatra error Rack::Lint::LintError: Status must be >=100 seen as integer

Tags: ruby, sinatra, unicorn

I'm creating a simple application with sinatra, and I'm deploying it with unicorn.

On local using `ruby webserver.rb` it works perfectly, but on production server, when executing with unicorn (without -D) it raise an error when calling an specific post route:

```
post '/save-preset' do
  preset = Preset.create_new params['preset_name'], params['data']
  session[:flash] = 'Preset Saved'
  {id: preset.id}.to_json
end
```

the error is:

```
Rack::Lint::LintError: Status must be >=100 seen as integer
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2-head/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/lint.rb:20:in `assert'
```

I know the logic of the action is being executed because I end with a new entry on my db.

This is also working fine on local.

I've searched over the internet about this error, but only found it to be related to other ruby webserver, it seem to me like the http status for the response is not valid, but i'm not specifying it and for others routes (even other `POST`) it works just fine.

Comment: One way to fix this is adding `status 200` on the route, but I don't understand why? other routes works without this. And in local, without unicorn it also works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hack for Lint:

```
module Rack
  class Lint
    def assert message, &block
    end
  end
end
```

It helped me with async requests in thin